# Can I run gnome-panel in Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: unity, 17.10, gnome-panel, gnome-shell

I had Ubuntu 16.04 but was stupid enough to upgrade to 17.04 and then 17.10.

In 16.04 I used Unity together with gnome panels. Not gnome shell but gnome panels. After the upgrade Ubuntu had switched to Gnome desktop. But gnome-panels would not start. Since Unity was still there, I tried to log in using Unity. That worked, but the desktop keeps reloading and reloading endlessly.

#### My questions:

1. How can I stop this endless reloading?
2. Is there a way to run gnome-panels with Gnome 3 (the new default desktop in Ubuntu)?

It doesn't tell me much, but the output of
`lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` is:

```
bjorn@bjorn-lifebook-u:~$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile
GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary) (rev 0
)
        Subsystem: Fujitsu Limited. Mobile GM965/GL960 Integ
rated Graphics Controller (primary)
        Kernel driver in use: i915
        Kernel modules: i915, intelfb
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/
L960 Integrated Graphics Controller (secondary) (rev 03)
        Subsystem: Fujitsu Limited. Mobile GM965/GL960 Integ
rated Graphics Controller (secondary)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Famil
y) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 03)
        Subsystem: Fujitsu Limited. 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB
 UHCI Controller
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I gave up on gnome-panels and simply installed ubuntu-mate-desktop. Then I used Mate Tweak to activate the advanced menu. That actually turned out to be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I don't know how many times I tried this, but suddely it worked. I logged in using Unity. While Unity was reloading endlessly, I pressed Alt+F2 and ran

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh lightdm
sudo service lightdm restart
```

and rebooted.
Now it seems to be stable and like it used to be.

Comment: Nope. It turned out to be just temporary. Now it is back to the endless reloading again and reconfigure doesn't seem to work anymore. So, is there a way to run gnome-panels with gnome 3? Or is there another way to get extra panels?